# Elastic search - sense plugin tokenize last 7 digits from right

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, sense

I have data indexed in this format 676767 2343423 2344444 32494444.I am trying to tokenize last 7 digits from the right. Pattern is working in online tool but the same is not working in sense plugin. 
Pattern : "pattern":   ".*([0-9]{7})" : Returns 6 digits including space. If the value is more than six then tokenizer is null.

Another pattern which shows error in sense plugin : .*(\d{7}) . Backslash shows error.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash, i.e. \\ instead of \

Comment: @Val: ES regex does not support `\d`, nor `\w`, nor `\s`... It does not support a lot of things and it is the least trouble with this Lucene regex flavor.

Comment: This is the output i am getting {
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": " 228128",
      "start_offset": 27,
      "end_offset": 34,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
} for input  text": "8765432123 23422334 1234564 228128". When i add more than 6 digits at the last then the response is {
  "tokens": []
}